# How to load and change the default option in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

**Code**

I am having a form like this in HTML:

```
<label for="alternativeGraph">Alternative graphs could be seen here:</label>
         <select id="selGraph" onchange="graphUpdate()" aria-label="Graph">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">Graph 1 (default)</option>
                <option value="2">Graph 2</option>
                <option value="3">Graph 3</option>
                <option value="4">Graph 4</option>
                <option value="5">Graph 5</option>
            </select>
      <button type="button" onclick="setDefault()"> Change default graph</button>
```

I am planning to load Graph 1 as my default option when the page is loaded, and to change my default graph with setDefault() function. Here is my JavaScript code for it:

```
function render(filename) {
fetch(filename).then(response  => response.text()).then(textAsString => 
     renderString(textAsString));
}

   
function graphUpdate(){
    let value = document.querySelector('#selGraph');
    let graph = ["graph_1.gv", "graph_2.gv", "graph_3.gv", "graph_4.gv", "graph_5.gv"]
    render(graph[value.selectedIndex]);
    
}

// function setDefault(){ # I am not sure about what should be added here...
//     let new_default_graph = document.querySelector("#selGraph");
//     new_default_graph.value = 
    

// }
```

**Issues**

The main problem is that when I load the website, Graph 1 ("graph_1.gv" file) is not loaded, despite of my choice as the default graph. Only when I clicked on the dropdown form did the graph show up. (Other graphs are still loaded, though).

**Questions:**

Are there any method that could read from my selected option and load it from the beginning? And also, what should I do with my `setDefault()` function so that when users choose option 3 for example, the website could save this option as the default one when being refreshed?

Comment: Simply add `render("graph_1.gv")` somewhere in your code so it renders on initial page load. You could even run it on `window.load`... `window.addEventListener("load", () => render("graph_1.gv"))`

Comment: Actually I did that before @Phil, but I would like to see is there any other solutions that would relate to my option form.

Comment: `<option value=“(array element index)”>` is confusing as hell. You could simply do `<option value=“graph_1.gv”>`

Comment: Also, the first array element is `array[“0”]`, not `array[“1”]` as you do in the code, — but that will be irrelevant with my previous comment taken into consideration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the web page takes time to load all the DOM components, maybe you should include a window.onload event function in your script, to call the graphUpdate() function after the page is fully loaded for the first time:

```
window.onload = graphUpdate;
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

To save the selected value you can use window.localStorage, which allows you to make the value persistent in the browser, so the event function can be as follows:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // 1 by default, in case there is nothing saved
  let selected = window.localStorage.getItem('selectedGraph') || 1;
  document.querySelector('#selGraph').selectedIndex = selected;
  graphUpdate();
}
```

Then the graphUpdate function should include a line to store the value:

```
function graphUpdate(){
    let value = document.querySelector('#selGraph');
    let graph = ["graph_1.gv", "graph_2.gv", "graph_3.gv", "graph_4.gv", "graph_5.gv"]
    render(graph[value.selectedIndex]);
    window.localStorage.setItem('selectedGraph', value.selectedIndex)
}
```

Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about the onload function here :))) So just another question, how would you change the default choice in my ```setDefault()``` function?

Comment: I updated my answer by including a solution with window.localStorage

Answer (score 1):

Provided your JS code runs after the document elements exist (either by placing the `<script>` tag after or using `defer`), you can simply execute your `graphUpdate()` function.

To save default options, I would use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Finally, attribute-based event listeners like `onchange` and `onclick` should be discouraged.

```html
<label for="alternativeGraph">Alternative graphs could be seen here:</label>
<select id="selGraph" aria-label="Graph">
  <!-- values are easier to work with than indexes -->
  <option value="graph_1.gv">Graph 1</option>
  <option value="graph_2.gv">Graph 2</option>
  <option value="graph_3.gv">Graph 3</option>
  <option value="graph_4.gv">Graph 4</option>
  <option value="graph_5.gv">Graph 5</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="setDefaultGraphBtn">Change default graph</button>
```

```js
// Constants
const DEFAULT_GRAPH_KEY = "default-graph";
const DEFAULT_GRAPH = "graph_1.gv";

// Elements
const graphSelect = document.getElementById("selGraph");
const btn = document.getElementById("setDefaultGraphBtn");

// Functions
const render = async (filename) => {
  const res = await fetch(filename);
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`${filename}: ${res.status} ${res.statusText}`);
  }

  renderString(await res.text());
};

const graphUpdate = () => {
  render(graphSelect.value);
};

const setDefaultGraph = () => {
  const val = graphSelect.value;
  localStorage.setItem(DEFAULT_GRAPH_KEY, val);
  graphSelect.querySelectorAll("option").forEach((opt) => {
    // remove any previous "default" text
    opt.textContent = opt.textContent.replace(" (default)", "");
    // add "default" text
    if (opt.value === val) {
      opt.textContent += " (default)";
    }
  });
};

// Bind event listeners
graphSelect.addEventListener("change", graphUpdate);
btn.addEventListener("click", setDefaultGraph);

// Get localStorage value or default
const defaultGraph = localStorage.getItem(DEFAULT_GRAPH_KEY) ?? DEFAULT_GRAPH;

// set default selected
graphSelect.value = defaultGraph;

// Now run functions to initialise
setDefaultGraph();
graphUpdate();
```